# Firefox Clippings add-on no longer working when coding Apex in the browser

Tags: firefox

I prefer coding directly through the UI rather than using an IDE. In other words, `Setup` > `Develop` > `Apex Classes` > `Edit`.

[image: Code Screenshot]

(Yup, you heard me right - so deal with it and let's move on. ;)

In the past, I've used the [Firefox Clippings add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/clippings/) to quickly paste in commonly used phrases such as the beginning of a debug statement.  Recently, however, Clippings has stopped working for my SFDC browser coding.  Instead of pasting in the clipped text, I hear that chirp sound that indicates an error.

It still works as expected in other areas of SFDC, such as when entering data into a long text field on a page layout; it just doesn't work when editing code.  Anyone else experienced this?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by coding directly in the browser. Can you add screenshots?

Comment: Sure, just uploaded one.

Comment: Are you aware of how to [open the web console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Opening_the_Web_Console)? Do you see any errors there when you try to use this add-on?

Comment: I can respect the UI coding...now if you said you were using the UI AND Internet Explorer I would question your sanity or brand you a very patient saint....

Comment: At least they stopped supporting IE6...

Comment: I never did figure out why Clippings no longer works for coding in the browser, but the MyWords add-on seems to do the trick:  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mywords/